# What is the purpose behind the static final fields in the Collections class?

Tags: java, collections

The Collections class has three static final fields called EMPTY_LIST, EMPTY_MAP and EMPTY_SET.  They are all interface references, and they are final. So what is their purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is that you don't need to construct new instances of immutable empty datastructures. You can simply reuse the existing ones. These fields had been introduced before Generics. With Generics you want to use the accessor methods instead because they are type-safe in a Generics way. I.e. instead of `Collections.EMPTY_SET` you want to use `Collections.emptySet()`. Fields cannot declare type parameters, but methods can.

Here's an example where an empty collection comes in handy.

Let's assume you have a function which returns the sum of a List of Integers, and you want to test that when you pass the empty list, it returns 0. The test would look like this:

```
public class IntSumTest {
    @Test
    public void givenEmptyList_whenSumming_thenReturnsZero() {
        assertEquals(0, sum(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

I rarely use empty collections outside test classes, so I couldn't think of another example yet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I still don't understand the need for an interface reference to an empty immutable set.. What will you do with it?

Comment: You will use it wherever you need an empty collection and you don't need it to be mutable.

Comment: Again, can you give me a concrete example of how you will use an empty immutable collection?

Comment: @ChristianHujer, I think I undertand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the JDK7 source, eg.:

```
/**
 * Returns the empty set (immutable).  This set is serializable.
 * Unlike the like-named field, this method is parameterized.
 *
 * <p>This example illustrates the type-safe way to obtain an empty set:
 * <pre>
 *     Set&lt;String&gt; s = Collections.emptySet();
 * </pre>
 * Implementation note:  Implementations of this method need not
 * create a separate <tt>Set</tt> object for each call.   Using this
 * method is likely to have comparable cost to using the like-named
 * field.  (Unlike this method, the field does not provide type safety.)
 *
 * @see #EMPTY_SET
 * @since 1.5
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> Set<T> emptySet() {
    return (Set<T>) EMPTY_SET;
}
```

That should answer your question. They're even mentioned in the [Collections JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) as being immutable, thus safe to have only one of, and thus `static`.

Cheers,

Comment: The question is about the constants, not the methods. I expect OP to wonder even more why another method is needed to return that constant. You answer that second concern, but do not address OP's question at all.

Comment: Both the documentation and the source clearly show what the fields are used for, so in my opinion there is no more definitive answer than this.

Comment: @Gimby If you imply that the fields are there *for* these methods, then you have it upside-down. The methods are there for the *fields* to be more useful, and the fields are public API on their own.

Comment: I'm not going to go into a discussion about that, I agree to disagree.

Comment: @Gimby There is nothing to disagree about, really, considering that the fields were there several versions before the methods were added.

Answer (score 2):

They are the values returned by `Collections.empty{List,Map,Set}()`.

As the javadoc specifies that all elements returned by these methods are immutable, it makes no sense to have more than one at any time ;)

Answer (score 2):

An API conforming to best practices will never have a collection-returning method return `null`. If there are no items to return, an empty collection should be returned.

Furthermore, while calling into some API which doesn't tolerate `null`s, you may have a possibly `null` collection reference which you must turn into one which is always non-null.

In all such cases it will be better for the overall application performance to reuse a single instance which represents an *immutable, empty* collection than waste time and memory on creating a new one each time. The JDK provides you with such singletons.

Comment: I posted a response earlier asking for a concrete example of when you need an immutable null reference, but re-reading your response, I think I understand.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I have a follow-up question-  These three empty interface references, what objects are they pointing to?  For example, does the reference EMPTY_LIST point to an instantiated object of the LIST type with no elements?  If so, what is the concrete class of this object?

Comment: You can easily verify that, and a lot more, on the actual OpenJDK source code. In an IDE, "go to declaration" of `EMPTY_LIST`. If that's not available, google for "grepcode java collections" and find a link to the Collections class on the GrepCode site.